# replicated operation when I use shift, enumerate? or a Debug?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm using python to calculate differences between rows in 2 columns. I use a function to subtract row1-row2, then elevate to square and apply the square root to eliminate negative sign. Then the function moves to row2-row3 and so on for a separation of one row, the result is saved in a column. The next step is to calculate the subtraction for row1-row3 and keep with that sequence until the end of the values... To establish the separation between rows I construct a list of shifts. Apparently my list is fine. The data were I use is the following:

```
df1
Out[44]: 
   TRACK_ID  POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_T
0         0           1           1       35.36
1         0           2           2       35.52
2         0           3           3       35.68
3         0           4           4       35.84
4         0           1           1       35.36
5         0           4           3       34.88
6         0           2           3       34.40
7         0           6           4       33.92
8         0           4           2       33.44
```

This is my output:

```
rad
Out[28]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  1.414214  2.828427  4.242641  0.000000  3.605551  2.236068  2.236068   
1  1.414214  2.828427  1.414214  2.236068  1.000000  4.472136  4.472136   
2  1.414214  2.828427  1.000000  1.000000  3.162278  1.414214  1.414214   
3  4.242641  1.000000  2.236068  2.000000  2.000000       NaN       NaN   
4  3.605551  2.236068  5.830952  3.162278       NaN       NaN       NaN   
5  2.000000  2.236068  1.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
6  4.123106  2.236068       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
7  2.828427       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
8       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

          7   8  
0  3.162278 NaN  
1       NaN NaN  
2       NaN NaN  
3       NaN NaN  
4       NaN NaN  
5       NaN NaN  
6       NaN NaN  
7       NaN NaN  
8       NaN NaN
```

How you can see the column 5 and 6 is the same and then jumps to the correct series in column 7

My whole code is the following:

```
df1 = df[['TRACK_ID','POSITION_X','POSITION_Y','POSITION_T']].copy()



#Parameter input

N = df1.groupby('TRACK_ID').size()          
max_time = N*(0.160)
frames = max_time/N
t_step=frames.item()


data = pd.DataFrame({'N':N,'max_time':max_time,'frames':frames})

print(data)

t=np.linspace(0.160, max_time.item(), N)




def radial(df1, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']):


        tau = t.copy()
        shifts = np.divide(tau,t_step).astype(float)
        print(shifts)
        radials = list()

        for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            diffs = np.array(df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift))
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            r = np.sqrt(sqdist)
            radials.append(r)


        radial_disp = pd.DataFrame({'radials':radials})
        return radials


radial_d = radial(df1, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])

radd = pd.DataFrame.from_records(radial_d) #horizontal
rad = radd.transpose() #vertical
```

When I print my list of shifts all looks nice:

```
shifts
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
```

So, I don't get it the problem, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the bug in your code.

Just change:

```
for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
```

to:

```
for i, shift in enumerate(np.round(shifts,0)):
```

Should fix your problem.

The problem is your original shifts variable is in float and when you do:

```
list(enumerate(shifts))
```

It ouputs the following:

```
Out[1923]: 
[(0, 1.0),
 (1, 2.0),
 (2, 3.0),
 (3, 4.0),
 (4, 5.0),
 (5, 6.0),
 (6, 6.9999999999999991),
 (7, 8.0),
 (8, 9.0)]
```

When 6.9999999999999991 is cast to a int, it becomes 6 instead of 7.

Comment: awesome! this was very hidden, Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped.